# Making AJAX calls from HTML file

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I'm developing an Android app with PhoneGap. What PhoneGap does, is to create a mini-browser, with nothing but the phone's back key, and let's you build static HTML files, which act as your app.

Now my problem is, how do I make AJAX calls from a HTML file to a certain domain? Wouldn't the AJAX call fail because the domains are different? `JSONP` is not an option, because I also need to `POST` to the URL, and JSONP does only `GET`.

Do I need to change something in Apache's (2.x) settings, like the "allow origin" (or something similar) header?